# Formatting the negative number input to positive number surrounding with braces using number format component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs, typescript

I have the below code on my current component. The requirement is when a user enters the negative number it should convert to positive number and surrounded with braces. For example if a user enters -200 it should be converted to (200).

The current code is adding the brackets '(' when entered negative number but the negative symbol is not being removed.

I need help with how to remove the negative '-' symbol

```
const Format: React.FC<Props> = ({
  includePrefix,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const prefix: string | undefined =
    includePrefix === true || includePrefix === undefined ? '$' : undefined;
  return (
    <NumberFormat
      autoComplete="off"
      thousandSeparator
      isNumericString
      prefix={Number(otherProps.value) < 0 ? `(${prefix || ''}` : prefix}
      suffix={Number(otherProps.value) < 0 ? ')' : ''}
      allowNegative
      {...otherProps}
    />
  );
};

/// <reference types="react" />

//exclude types from the InputHTMLAttributes
declare const {defaultValue, value, ...inputAttributes}: React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;
type InputAttributes = typeof inputAttributes;


declare module "react-number-format" {

  export interface NumberFormatState {
    value?: string;
    numAsString?: string;
  }

  export interface NumberFormatValues {
    floatValue: number;
    formattedValue: string;
    value: string;
  }

  export type FormatInputValueFunction = (inputValue: string) => string;

  export interface SyntheticInputEvent
    extends React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement> {
    readonly target: HTMLInputElement;
    data: any;
  }

  export interface NumberFormatProps
    extends InputAttributes {
    thousandSeparator?: boolean | string;
    decimalSeparator?: boolean | string;
    thousandsGroupStyle?: 'thousand' | 'lakh' | 'wan';
    decimalScale?: number;
    fixedDecimalScale?: boolean;
    displayType?: 'input' | 'text';
    prefix?: string;
    suffix?: string;
    format?: string | FormatInputValueFunction;
    removeFormatting?: (formattedValue: string) => string;
    mask?: string | string[];
    value?: number | string;
    defaultValue?: number | string;
    isNumericString?: boolean;
    customInput?: React.ComponentType<any>;
    allowNegative?: boolean;
    allowEmptyFormatting?: boolean;
    onValueChange?: (values: NumberFormatValues) => void;
    /**
     * these are already included in React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
     * onKeyDown: Function;
     * onMouseUp: Function;
     * onChange: Function;
     * onFocus: Function;
     * onBlur: Function;
     */
    type?: 'text' | 'tel'  | 'password';
    isAllowed?: (values: NumberFormatValues) => boolean;
    renderText?: (formattedValue: string) => React.ReactNode;
    getInputRef?: ((el: HTMLInputElement) => void) | React.Ref<any>;
    allowedDecimalSeparators?: Array<string>;
    [key: string]: any;
  }

  class NumberFormat extends React.Component<NumberFormatProps, any> {}
  export default NumberFormat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
prefix={Number(otherProps.value) < 0 ? `(${-prefix || ''}` : prefix}
```

Comment: I see the below error 
```
const prefix: string | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: can you show the code of the NumberFormat component

Comment: Added to the code

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you destructure the value prop like so?

```
const CurrencyFormat: React.FC<CurrencyFieldProps> = ({
  includePrefix,
  value,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const prefix: string | undefined =
    includePrefix === true || includePrefix === undefined ? '$' : undefined;
  return (
    <NumberFormat
      autoComplete="off"
      thousandSeparator
      isNumericString
      prefix={Number(value) < 0 ? `(${prefix || ''}` : prefix}
      suffix={Number(value) < 0 ? ')' : ''}
      decimalScale={2}
      fixedDecimalScale
      allowNegative
      isAllowed={(values) => {
        const { formattedValue, floatValue } = values;
        return formattedValue === '' || floatValue <= MAX_CURRENCY_NUMBER;
      }}
      value={String(Math.abs(Number(value)))} // Make it positive
      {...otherProps}
    />
  );
};
```

Check this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/negativecurrencyformat-syeowd?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Sorry it didnt work and even the brackets are added only after the page is refreshed using this code

Comment: It is impossible for the value to remain negative. `Math.abs()` will always make any number positive. Your error must be somewhere else. You could create an interactive example in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/), then we can help you further. But this is hard to debug without running and debugging the code

Comment: Its such a big project.. how to add. the html code when its not in my project .. sorry new to this. is there a way we have chat on stack overflow

Comment: I think the "otherProps" is over riding but i am not sure

Comment: I tried this too     
`value={Number(otherProps.value) < 0 ? String(Math.abs(Number(otherProps.value))): otherProps.value} `

Comment: This was WAAY harder than I thought. It could be a start for you to build upon.  Check [it](https://codesandbox.io/s/negativecurrencyformat-syeowd?file=/src/App.js) out.

Comment: SO i need to add **customInput** to my code now. I tried using your sample in the below `customInput={otherProps.value.replace(/^-/, "")}` and it didnt work

Comment: Can you check this link 'https://codesandbox.io/s/negativecurrencyformat-forked-o83yz8'

Comment: `react-number-format@5.1.1` does not export a default class. `import NumberFormat, { NumberFormatProps } from 'react-number-format';` Should be changed to `import { NumericFormat, NumberFormatProps } from "react-number-format";` [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/negativecurrencyformat-forked-hrr1yn?file=/src/App.js:41-112)

Comment: my current version of react-number-format is `react-number-format: ^4.3.1` So do you think i cannot achieve my work in this. version

Comment: I tried upgrading to version `react-number-format@5.1.1` and i see the below error 
`Attempted import error: 'react-number-format' does not contain a default export (imported as 'NumericFormat')`

Comment: You can, all the features you need are available in `4.3.1`. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/negativecurrencyformat-syeowd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: yes, it is exactly what i said above

Comment: I was planing to use OnBlur and i read somewhere that `4.3.1` doesnt support. If so then how would i remove the negative symbol when the user enters it. Can you add `customInput` to my code. Because i tried and i am getting error.

Comment: Can you provide a .tsx file in your sandbox code

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the absolute of your value to `NumberFormat` the `value` prop is the one that you need to remove the `-` from, like this:

```
    <NumberFormat
      autoComplete="off"
      thousandSeparator
      isNumericString
      prefix={Number(otherProps.value) < 0 ? `(${prefix || ''}` : prefix}
      suffix={Number(otherProps.value) < 0 ? ')' : ''}
      allowNegative
      {...otherProps}
      value={Math.abs(otherProps.value)} // <= try adding this line 
    />
```